# Image map works in Chrome but not in IE

Tags: javascript, html, area, imagemap

So I have this map code, which seems fine in Chrome but today an IE user reported that the clickable areas weren't clickable.  (Sorry that's vague; not sure if she had mouseover behavior or anything.  I can check if that's important.)

Code:

```
<img id="flowchart" src="images/course-flowchart.png" usemap="#Map" />
<map name="Map" id="Map">
  <area shape="rect" coords="289,14,397,68" onMouseOver="hoverEss();" onClick="clickEss();" />
  <area shape="rect" coords="331,70,356,115" onMouseOver="hoverEssPre();" />
  <area shape="rect" coords="289,115,397,171" onMouseOver="hoverPre();" onClick="clickPre();" />
  <area shape="rect" coords="330,172,356,216" onMouseOver="hoverPreHsmp();" />
  <area shape="rect" coords="289,215,397,271" onMouseOver="hoverHsmp();" onClick="clickHsmp();" />
  <area shape="rect" coords="326,271,361,318" onMouseOver="hoverHsmp10c();" />
  <area shape="rect" coords="289,318,397,373" onMouseOver="hover10c();" onClick="click10c();" />
  <area shape="rect" coords="224,382,341,422" onMouseOver="hover10c201();" />
  <area shape="rect" coords="344,382,464,422" onMouseOver="hover10c202();" />
  <area shape="rect" coords="180,422,288,478" onMouseOver="hover201();" onClick="click201();" />
  <area shape="rect" coords="396,422,504,478" onMouseOver="hover202();" onClick="click202();" />
  <area shape="rect" coords="434,478,467,524" onMouseOver="hover202302();" />
  <area shape="rect" coords="398,525,504,580" onMouseOver="hover302();" onClick="click302();" />
  <area shape="rect" coords="220,478,249,524" onMouseOver="hover201301();" />
  <area shape="poly" coords="295,467,400,516,390,539,283,488" onMouseOver="hover201302();" />
  <area shape="rect" coords="180,525,288,580" onMouseOver="hover301();" onClick="click301();" />
  <area shape="rect" coords="68,492,219,524" onMouseOver="hover20131();" />
  <area shape="rect" coords="26,524,133,580" onMouseOver="hover31();" />

</map>
```

Here's the page if you want to see it in situ:
https://media.norquest.ca/ace/math/uosc/math-placement.shtml

Thanks for any ideas!
JF

Comment: [According to MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/img#Browser_compatibility), `usemap` is only partially supported by IE. This feature may not work on IE due to lack of implementation.

Comment: Ugh.  Rotten news, but thank you!